# hello please let me know whats wrong with this script for find Reuse R value

Tags: value, nonce

```
hello friends here is the code to find reuse R values of bitcoin transaction but unfortunately it is not scanning more than 51 transaction secondly it can only use one address at a time and i want to use text file to check multiple addresses as well as i want to save the output in a text file please help me to sort out
```

> import json

> import urllib2

> import time

> import sys

> #for some reason blockchain.info api-chain is 59711 blocks short..

> blockstart = 170399

> blockstart += 59711

> blockcount = urllib2.urlopen("https://blockchain.info/de/q/getblockcount").read()

> print "WELCOME TO R-scan v0.1.2!"

> print "ADDRESS-R-SCAN: "

> addr = raw_input("type address:  ")

> urladdr = "https://blockchain.info/de/rawaddr/" + str(addr)

> #control api-url

> print urladdr

> addrdata = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(urladdr))

> print "Data for pubkey: " + str(addr)

> print "number of txs: " + str(addrdata['n_tx'])

> #tx-details:

> y = -0

> inputs = []

> while y < addrdata['n_tx']:

> print "#################################################################################"

> print "TX nr :" + str(y+1)

> print "hash: " + str(addrdata['txs'][y]['hash'])

> print "number of inputs: " + str(addrdata['txs'][y]['vin_sz'])

> #only if

> #if addrdata['txs'][y]['vin_sz'] > 1:

> zy = 0

> while zy < addrdata['txs'][y]['vin_sz']:

> ```
>   print "Input-ScriptNR " + str(zy+1) + " :" + str(addrdata['txs'][y]['inputs'][zy]['script'])
> ```

> ```
>   inputs.append(addrdata['txs'][y]['inputs'][zy]['script'])
> ```

> ```
>   zy += 1
> ```

> y += 1

> print "compare: "

> xi = 0

> zi = 1

> lenx = len(inputs)

> alert = 0

> #compare the sig values in each input script

> while xi < lenx-1:

> x = 0

> while x < lenx-zi:

> ```
>   if inputs[xi][10:74] == inputs[x+zi][10:74]:
> ```

> ```
>       print "In Input NR: " + str(xi) + "[global increment] " + str(inputs[xi])
> ```

> ```
>       print('\a')
> ```

> ```
>                    print "Resued R-Value: "
> ```

> ```
>       print inputs[x+zi][10:74]
> ```

> ```
>                    alert += 1
> ```

> ```
>   x += 1
> ```

> zi += 1

> xi += 1

> #check duplicates

> #alert when everything ok

> if alert < 1:

> print "Good pubKey. No problems."

> sys.exit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my code located [here](https://gist.github.com/DesWurstes/8bfeac78dad31011dddd511cb0c1526d):

- In your working directory (that you cd'd into) create an `addr.txt` containing your list of addresses separated by space or a newline.
- Run it as `python3 rscan.py 2>out.txt`. It'll print the progress and if anything bad is found it'll be in `out.txt` in your working directory.

Comment: thank you very much sir! please tell me is there any script which can scan blockchain for specific signature

Comment: thank you very much sir! please tell me is there any script which can scan blockchain for specific signature

Comment: This script collects all signatures from an address and checks for all matches. If it isn't, what do you specifically need?

Comment: the script scan the entire blockchain and search for the signatures and find the match of given signature input

Comment: I don't have it, maybe you can ask about it in a new question? It sounds difficult to code since block explorers don't index by signature

Comment: Dear MCCCS your script work fine for me and i got a key which has the reuse value for many times but the script is printing transaction input number and i don't know how to find it because signature is not indexed in blockchain. if it can print hash of transaction which has the reuse r value it will be bit easy to trace the transaction. please let me know if you have the solution.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnanAlam Here is my updated code that also prints hashes: https://gist.github.com/DesWurstes/937de5ce335fe255eccc23b2abded49e